# Отправка валидируемой формы со второго клика по submit, как исправить? А также как включить checkbox в валидацию?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть форма, сделал валидацию. Все работает, но есть одно **НО**.

Если в одном из полей формы ввести невалидные данные и нажать на submit и после исправить невалидные данные и сразу кликнуть на submit, то получается срабатывает `focusout();` и форма не отправляется. Чтобы отправить форму необходимо второй раз кликнуть на submit.

**Помогите исправить ситуацию, чтобы при любом раскладе форма отправлялась с первого раза (если все `.val()`) валидные.**

**Также подскажите, как правильно включить checkbox в валидацию?**

Заранее, благодарю!

```js
var errorNull2 = true, errorEmail2 = true, errorName2 = true, checkBox = true;

var ticketAuthor = $("#ticket-author"); // Имя
var ticketAuthorEmail = $("#ticket-author-email"); // Email

var minNameVal = 2; // Минимальное количество вводимых символов в поле Имя
var maxNameVal = 50; // Максиимальное количество вводимых символов в поле Имя
var nameMinMax = [minNameVal,maxNameVal]; // Массив мини. и макс. количество символов в поле Имя
var patternName = "[a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ0-9_. -]{" + nameMinMax +"}";

var patternEmail = /[a-z\d-]+([\.\_]?[a-z\d-]+)+@[a-zа-я\d-]+(\.[a-zа-я]{2,6})/g;


/* Функция проверки поля на null в отдельной переменной */
var checkNull2 = function(){
$(this).val($(this).val().trim());
var value = $(this).val();
if (value =="") {
 if($(this).is(ticketAuthor)){
  $("#name_valid").css("display"," inline-block");
  $("#name_valid").html("Поле Имя нужно заполнить");
   $(this).removeClass("ok-textbox").addClass("err-textbox");    
 } 
 errorNull2 = true;  
 }else{
  if($(this).is(ticketAuthor)){
   $("#name_valid").css("display"," none");
   $("#name_valid").html("");
   $(this).removeClass("err-textbox");
  }  
  errorNull2 = false; 
 }
};

/* Проверяем значения полей Имя и Email на null в момент когда они теряют фокус */
$("#ticket-author").focusout(checkNull2);
$("#ticket-author-email").focusout(checkNull2);



/* Проверка поля Имя */
$("#ticket-author").focusout(function(){
  var value = $(this).val();  
  if(value == ""){
 $(this).removeClass("ok-textbox").addClass("err-textbox");
 $("#name_valid").css("display"," inline-block");
 $("#name_valid").html("Поле Имя пустое");
 errorName2 = true;
  }else if (value != value.match(patternName)){
 $(this).removeClass("ok-textbox").addClass("err-textbox");
 $("#name_valid").css("display"," inline-block");
 $("#name_valid").html("От 2 до 50 символов. Только буквы, цифры и символы: <b>. – _</b>"); 
    errorName2 = true; 
  }else{  
   if (value.length >= minNameVal){
   $("#name_valid").css("display"," none");
   $("#name_valid").html(""); 
   $(this).removeClass("err-textbox").addClass("ok-textbox");
   $("#submit_valid").css("display"," none");
   $("#submit_valid").html("");
   errorName2 = false;
 }  
  }  
});


/* Проверяем корректность E-mail */
$("#ticket-author-email").focusout(function(){
var value = $(this).val().trim();

if(value == ""){   
 $("#email_valid").css("display"," inline-block");
 $("#email_valid").html("Поле Email нужно заполнить");  
 $(this).removeClass("ok-textbox").addClass("err-textbox");    
 errorEmail2 = true; 
  } 
  else if(value != value.match(patternEmail)) {
 $("#email_valid").css("display"," inline-block");
 $("#email_valid").html("Введите реальный Email");
    $(this).removeClass("ok-textbox").addClass("err-textbox");
    errorEmail2 = true; 
  } 
  else{
   $("#email_valid").css("display"," none");
   $("#email_valid").html(""); 
   $(this).removeClass("err-textbox").addClass("ok-textbox");
   $("#submit_valid").css("display"," none");
   $("#submit_valid").html("");
   errorEmail2 = false;
  }
});

// В результате клика по кнопке отправить если ошибок заполнения нет то форма отправляется иначе получаем сообщение об ошибке
$("#submit").click(function (){
  
  var author = ticketAuthor.val().trim();
  var email = ticketAuthorEmail.val().trim();


// проверка на наличие ошибок
if (errorNull2 || errorEmail2 || errorName2){
   
  if(author == ""){
 $("#name_valid").css("display"," inline-block");
 $("#name_valid").html("Поле Имя нужно заполнить");
  ticketAuthor.removeClass("ok-textbox").addClass("err-textbox");
 }
   
  if(email == ""){
 $("#email_valid").css("display"," inline-block");
 $("#email_valid").html("Поле Email нужно заполнить");
  ticketAuthorEmail.removeClass("ok-textbox").addClass("err-textbox");    
  }

$("#submit_valid").css("display"," inline-block");
$("#submit_valid").html("Ошибки в полях!"); 
 
 // блокировка отправки формы
 return false;
 
  }else{
    $("#submit_valid").css("display"," none");
 $("#submit_valid").html("");
 console.log("Ошибок нет!");
  }     
});
```

```css
textarea:focus,input:focus,button:focus{
 outline:0!important;
}

.err-textbox {
 box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgb(255,0,0);   
}

.ok-textbox {
 box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgb(124,245,124);   
}

#pagetitle_valid,#editor_valid,#name_valid,#email_valid,#submit_valid{
 display:none;
 padding: 1px 5px 5px;
 color: red;
 font-size: 12px;
}

.form-group b {
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #f5dfdf;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!-- форма -->
<form action="" method="get" id="ticketForm" class="well create">
 
 
<div class="form-group">
 <span id="name_valid"></span> 
 <label for="ticket-author">Имя</label><span class="error"></span>     
 <input type="text" name="author_vo" id="ticket-author" class="form-control input__no-radius" placeholder="Ваше имя" maxlength="50" value=""> 
</div>
 
<div class="form-group">
 <span id="email_valid"></span>  
 <label for="ticket-author-email">Ваш Email</label><span class="error"></span>      
 <input type="email" name="email_author_vo" id="ticket-author-email" class="form-control input__no-radius" placeholder="Ваш Email" maxlength="50" value="">   
</div>

<div class="form-group">   
 <div style="float:left;"> 
 <input class="form-control radio_poll" type="checkbox" id="pre_poll_choice" name="pre_poll_choice" value="off">
 <label for="pre_poll_choice" style="margin-top: 10px;">Даю согласие на обработку персональных данных</label>
 </div>
</div>   

<div class="form-actions row"><span id="submit_valid"></span>
 <div class="move-right">
  <input type="submit" class="more buttons blue" name="draft" id="submit" value="Отправить вопрос"> 
 </div>
</div>  
<div class="end"></div>

</form><!-- / форма -->


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Я могу исправить, но не буду. У вас архитектура неправильная. Зачем давать пользователю возможность отправлять данные если они не заполнены или невалидны? Как правильно: ставите disabled на кнопку, при изменение данных в одной форме проверяете её на валидность, если всё нормально то переводите фокус на другие незаполненные и т.д. В итоге когда все формы заполнены, вы снимаете disabled с кнопки и уже отправляете валидные данные

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, будет разумно поменять ивент `focusout` на какой-нибудь другой, например, на `on()`.
Focusout, по моему, не совсем подходит для решении этой задачи.

**UPD**

Что касается `checkbox`-а, используйте `$('.checkbox').is(':checked')` в условии, чтобы определить стоит ли галочка.

```js
var errorNull2 = true, errorEmail2 = true, errorName2 = true, checkBox = true;

var ticketAuthor = $("#ticket-author"); // Имя
var ticketAuthorEmail = $("#ticket-author-email"); // Email

var minNameVal = 2; // Минимальное количество вводимых символов в поле Имя
var maxNameVal = 50; // Максиимальное количество вводимых символов в поле Имя
var nameMinMax = [minNameVal,maxNameVal]; // Массив мини. и макс. количество символов в поле Имя
var patternName = "[a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ0-9_. -]{" + nameMinMax +"}";

var patternEmail = /[a-z\d-]+([\.\_]?[a-z\d-]+)+@[a-zа-я\d-]+(\.[a-zа-я]{2,6})/g;


/* Функция проверки поля на null в отдельной переменной */
var checkNull2 = function(){
$(this).val($(this).val().trim());
var value = $(this).val();
if (value =="") {
 if($(this).is(ticketAuthor)){
  $("#name_valid").css("display"," inline-block");
  $("#name_valid").html("Поле Имя нужно заполнить");
   $(this).removeClass("ok-textbox").addClass("err-textbox");    
 } 
 errorNull2 = true;  
 }else{
  if($(this).is(ticketAuthor)){
   $("#name_valid").css("display"," none");
   $("#name_valid").html("");
   $(this).removeClass("err-textbox");
  }  
  errorNull2 = false; 
 }
};

/* Проверяем значения полей Имя и Email на null в момент когда они теряют фокус */
$(document).on('input', '#ticket-author', checkNull2);
$(document).on('input', '#ticket-author-email', checkNull2);



/* Проверка поля Имя */
$(document).on('input', '#ticket-author', function(){
  var value = $(this).val();  
  if(value == ""){
 $(this).removeClass("ok-textbox").addClass("err-textbox");
 $("#name_valid").css("display"," inline-block");
 $("#name_valid").html("Поле Имя пустое");
 errorName2 = true;
  }else if (value != value.match(patternName)){
 $(this).removeClass("ok-textbox").addClass("err-textbox");
 $("#name_valid").css("display"," inline-block");
 $("#name_valid").html("От 2 до 50 символов. Только буквы, цифры и символы: <b>. – _</b>"); 
    errorName2 = true; 
  }else{  
   if (value.length >= minNameVal){
   $("#name_valid").css("display"," none");
   $("#name_valid").html(""); 
   $(this).removeClass("err-textbox").addClass("ok-textbox");
   $("#submit_valid").css("display"," none");
   $("#submit_valid").html("");
   errorName2 = false;
 }  
  }  
});


/* Проверяем корректность E-mail */
$(document).on('input', '#ticket-author-email', function(){
var value = $(this).val().trim();

if(value == ""){   
 $("#email_valid").css("display"," inline-block");
 $("#email_valid").html("Поле Email нужно заполнить");  
 $(this).removeClass("ok-textbox").addClass("err-textbox");    
 errorEmail2 = true; 
  } 
  else if(value != value.match(patternEmail)) {
 $("#email_valid").css("display"," inline-block");
 $("#email_valid").html("Введите реальный Email");
    $(this).removeClass("ok-textbox").addClass("err-textbox");
    errorEmail2 = true; 
  } 
  else{
   $("#email_valid").css("display"," none");
   $("#email_valid").html(""); 
   $(this).removeClass("err-textbox").addClass("ok-textbox");
   $("#submit_valid").css("display"," none");
   $("#submit_valid").html("");
   errorEmail2 = false;
  }
});

// В результате клика по кнопке отправить если ошибок заполнения нет то форма отправляется иначе получаем сообщение об ошибке
$("#submit").click(function (){
  
  var author = ticketAuthor.val().trim();
  var email = ticketAuthorEmail.val().trim();


// проверка на наличие ошибок
if (errorNull2 || errorEmail2 || errorName2){
   
  if(author == ""){
 $("#name_valid").css("display"," inline-block");
 $("#name_valid").html("Поле Имя нужно заполнить");
  ticketAuthor.removeClass("ok-textbox").addClass("err-textbox");
 }
   
  if(email == ""){
 $("#email_valid").css("display"," inline-block");
 $("#email_valid").html("Поле Email нужно заполнить");
  ticketAuthorEmail.removeClass("ok-textbox").addClass("err-textbox");    
  }

$("#submit_valid").css("display"," inline-block");
$("#submit_valid").html("Ошибки в полях!"); 
 
 // блокировка отправки формы
 return false;
 
  }else{
    $("#submit_valid").css("display"," none");
 $("#submit_valid").html("");
 console.log("Ошибок нет!");
  }     
});
```

```css
textarea:focus,input:focus,button:focus{
 outline:0!important;
}

.err-textbox {
 box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgb(255,0,0);   
}

.ok-textbox {
 box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgb(124,245,124);   
}

#pagetitle_valid,#editor_valid,#name_valid,#email_valid,#submit_valid{
 display:none;
 padding: 1px 5px 5px;
 color: red;
 font-size: 12px;
}

.form-group b {
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #f5dfdf;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!-- форма -->
<form action="" method="get" id="ticketForm" class="well create">
 
 
<div class="form-group">
 <span id="name_valid"></span>
 
 <label for="ticket-author">Имя</label><span class="error"></span>     
 <input type="text" name="author_vo" id="ticket-author" class="form-control input__no-radius" placeholder="Ваше имя" maxlength="50" value=""> 
</div>
 
<div class="form-group">
 <span id="email_valid"></span>
  
 <label for="ticket-author-email">Ваш Email</label><span class="error"></span>      
 <input type="email" name="email_author_vo" id="ticket-author-email" class="form-control input__no-radius" placeholder="Ваш Email" maxlength="50" value="">   
</div>

<div class="form-group">   
   <div style="float:left;"> 
    <input class="form-control radio_poll" type="checkbox" id="pre_poll_choice" name="pre_poll_choice" value="off">
    <label for="pre_poll_choice" style="margin-top: 10px;">Даю согласие на обработку персональных данных</label>
   </div>
</div>   

<div class="form-actions row"><span id="submit_valid"></span>
 <div class="move-right">
  <input type="submit" class="more buttons blue" name="draft" id="submit" value="Отправить вопрос">    
 </div>
</div>  
<div class="end"></div>

</form><!-- / форма -->


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: так все равно отправляется со второго раза

Comment: да, сначала `focusout` заменил не везде, сейчас же обновил ответ.

Comment: @ozoro также не понимаю зачем на один и тот же элемент ставить одинаковые события, можно же объединить, чтобы для каждого поля не писать 2 раза `focusout`.

Comment: Так это одно и тоже, что `keyup()` - проверка сразу при вводе и при совпадении с условиями валидации красные поля и надписи пропадают... НО мне так не надо, надо чтобы при вводе данных не проверялось в реальном времени. а только при потере фокуса или при `click()`, а в противном случае сразу после ввода поле становится невалидным и подсвечивается красным `outline`, я так уже делал, но это не то...

Comment: но `focusout`, как вы видите, не решает вашу проблему, поскольку пользователь обычно после ввода сразу кликает на сабмит. я вам предложил не решение, а альтернативу.

Comment: @ozoro метод `change` для чего придуман. Вызывайте его при изменении данных в форме [change](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8_%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F_change)

Comment: @mix "можно же объединить, чтобы для каждого поля не писать 2 раза `focusout`" Но я, к сожалению, далеко не программист... как говорится. если долго мучиться, что нибудь получится... но если можешь, подскажи как объединить

Comment: @ДенисНебесный ну если не сложно, подскажи как это сделать на реальном примере